# Mathematical operations with an operator variable - Java

Tags: java, math, operators

I have two variables of type `int` (called `int1` and `int2`) and a variable type `char` (which always saves a mathematical operator and is called `op`).  How can I do mathematical operations with these three variables? I have to do it manually, I can not use ScriptEngineManager for teacher's reasons

I can not do `int res = int1 + op + int2` because it adds the value that the variable `op` has in the ascii table.
How could I put these three variables together to do a mathematical operation according to the variable op?

The simplest way I have found to do it is the following:

```
int res = 0;
if (op == '+'){res=int1+int2;}
else if (op == '-'){res = int1-int2;}
else if (op == '*'){res = int1*int2;}
else {res = int1/int2;}
```

Is there any more elegant way than this? Thank you!

Comment: The answer is No there isn't.  You could use a switch statement rather than if/else, but you still need a separate branch for each operator.

Comment: Looks to me like you are on the right track. Keep going & keep up the good work.

Answer (score 5):

Create an enumeration that maps the operation character to a function of two ints.

```
enum Operator {
    ADD('+',(x,y)->x+y),
    SUBTRACT('-',(x,y)->x-y),
    MULTIPLY('*',(x,y)->x*y),
    DIVIDE('/',(x,y)->x/y),
    REMAINDER('%',(x,y)->x%y),
    POW('^',(x,y)->(int)Math.pow(x,y));

    char symbol;
    BiFunction<Integer,Integer,Integer> operation;

    Operator(final char symbol, final BiFunction<Integer,Integer,Integer> operation) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    public static Operator representedBy(final char symbol)
    {
        return Stream.of(Operator.values()).filter(operator->operator.symbol==symbol).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }

    public Integer apply(final int x,final int y)
    {
        return operation.apply(x,y);
    }
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final char op = '+';
    final int int1 = 1;
    final int int2 = 2;
    final Operator operator = Operator.representedBy(op);
    if (operator == null)
    {
        // handle bad character
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(operator.apply(int1,int2));
    }
}
```